# Quickfix python data dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, report, execution, quickfix

I am connecting to an order session but I get execution reports without ExecID field. I change the requirement to no for ExecID field in ExecutionReport messages from the data dictionary but quickfix still sends reject message. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please share your code snippets with necessary outputs for convey your problem effectively.

Comment: You cannot changed QuickFIx fields unilaterally. You forget about your counterparty, they might need it. Go and check your message formats decided with your other side.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you've changed in the data dictionary makes the ExecID optional rather than mandatory. If you wanted to remove "the requirement" altogether then you'd have to remove the ExecID from the fields making up an execution report in the data dictionary. However, if you did that and your cpty still sent it in the exec report (because it's still configured in their data dictionary) then it would (provided you're using your own DD validation) fail validation.

Why don't you want the ExecID field?
Why can't you ignore it if it's sent to you?

Comment: They send it in some messages, in some messages they don't send it. It is not important actually, I canceled data dictionary validation.